# Server address and port in nodejs and express using http.createServer

Tags: node.js, express

new to node and express. Need to know how to fetch the servers IP and Port. Tried a few things:

```
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express(); 
var http = require('http'); 
app.set('port',12346); 
var httpServer = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'));  
function getMethod(req,res) {
    console.log("Server Port is: "+ app.get('port'));
    // console.log("Server Port is: "+ httpServer.address);
    console.log("Connection Type: "+ req.protocol);
    res.send("Hello world!"); 
} 
app.get('/', getMethod);
```

In the code above app.get returns me the servers port but if I query httpServer.address it returns undefined and app.address().port returns an error.
Is there a way to get it without setting it in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`http.Server`'s](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) `listen` is asynchronous, and you should not call `address()` until the `listening` event has been dispatched (from the docs `Don't call server.address() until the 'listening' event has been emitted.`).

You can do this a few ways, subscribing to the `listening` callback:

```
httpServer.on('listening', function () {
  console.log(app.address().port)
})
```

Or simply using `app.listen` (which creates an `http.Server`) and checking the instance's port in the callback that `listen` accepts:

```
let appInstance = app.listen(1337, function () {
  console.log(`'Server listening at: ${appInstance.address().port}`)
})
```

This removes the need to `require` the `http` module and simplifies the code somewhat.

The `set`/`get` methods on `app` allow you to set and retrieve arbitrary values on an express application. Some of those values are "special" (see the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set)) and affect the behavior of the application, but there's nothing stopping you from setting a property like `port`; the issue there is that it won't actually change the `port` that the application listens on.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
console.log('Port :' + httpServer.address().port);
console.log('Server:' + httpServer.address().address);
```